# Why can't I type a single quote at the beginning of a cell in LibreOffice Calc when editing a CSV file?

Tags: csv, libreoffice

When editing a CSV file in LibreOffice Calc, I have found that it is not possible to type a single quote at the beginning of a cell for both numbers and strings. When attempting to do so, the quote is automatically removed, and is not present in the CSV file when it is saved.

I have already attempted to modify the AutoCorrect Options in the Tools menu and have also tried changing the cell formatting, but the issue persists.

Despite conducting extensive research online, I have not been able to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Because a single quote is used to force the following text to be treated as a *literal*, not a numeric expression. Escape with a second single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find the solution by myself. The first single quote have to be escaped by another single quote.

For example, let's say you want to enter the following string into a cell in a CSV file: `'example'`. If you add an extra single quote before the first one like this: `''example'`, the first single quote will be treated as a literal character and will appear in the cell. Both quotes will appears in the "formula" field at the top of the window.